# Add Date and time in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I have a date string taken from database. And it's like

```
$date = '2016-03-21 11:00:00';
```

And I have a time string taken from database.

```
$time = '02:30:00'
```

Is there a way to add these two and get like these in PHP?

```
$newtime =  '2016-03-21 13:30:00';
```

Comment: if they're coming from a database (presumably mysql), why not add it in the db since they're (hopefully) have datetime/time values? mysql is perfectly capable of doing `select datefimefield + timefield`-type math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` to transform your `$time` value:

```
$date = '2016-03-21 11:00:00';
$time = '02:30:00';

$str = "$date + ".preg_replace( '/:(\d+):(\d+)$/',' hours, \1 minutes, \2 seconds',$time );
$date = new DateTime( $str );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Will print:

```
2016-03-21 13:30:00
```

With `preg_replace` we transform `02:30:00` in `02 hours, 30 minutes, 00 seconds` and, postponing it to `$date`, we obtain this string:

```
2016-03-21 11:00:00 + 02 hours, 30 minutes, 00 seconds
```

directly accepted by `DateTime` class.

---

- Read more about [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this but:

```
$date = new DateTime($time);

$int = new DateInterval($date->format("\P\TH\Hi\Ms\S"));

$dateTime = new DateTime($date);

return $dateTime->add($int);
```